# Automorphism groups of 3-dimensional complex solvable Lie algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, lie-algebras

Where can I find a published paper concerning with the automorphism groups of **3-dimensional complex Lie algebras**.

Answer (score 3):

I have computed all automorphism groups of complex Lie algebras in dimension $3$ myself, it is not too much work. But of course, it has been done already in the literature. One reference I know is the following:

Harvey, A., 1979, Automorphisms of the Bianchi model Lie groups. J. Math. Phys. 20: 251–253.

Furthermore, in [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.2278.pdf) by Glad et. al., all such complex Lie algebras are classified, together with their automorphisms groups.
The automorphism groups have been determined in dimensions $4,5,6$ as well, also over the real numbers, see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.3376.pdf).